# islower() from cctype function not working in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that reads keyboard input to the @ symbol and that echoes the input except for digits, converting each uppercase character to lowercase, and vice versa.

Here's my code, so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    char ch;

    cout << "Enter characters: " << endl;
    while (cin.get(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '@')
            break;
        if (isdigit(ch))
            continue;
        if (islower(ch))
            ch = toupper(ch);
        if (isupper(ch))
            ch = tolower(ch);
        cout << ch;


    }



    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code, but somemhow, when I type characters, it converts only uppercase letters to lowercase letters, not lowercase letters to uppercase letters.
For example, my output was:

```
Enter characters: 
Hello       // my input
hello       // output
```

As you can see, it only converts uppercase letter to lowercase letter and didn't convert any lowercase letters to uppercase letters like it's supposed to.

Is there something wrong with my code? If there is, I really can't find it. 
I am a newbie to C++, I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would have been solved by stepping through the code in a debugger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You convert lowercase letters to uppercase and then convert them back again. You should use `else if` to avoid unnecessary judgement:

```
if (islower(ch))
    ch = toupper(ch);
else if (isupper(ch))
    ch = tolower(ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

If ch is a lower-case letter, you make it an upper-case letter here:

```
    if (islower(ch))
        ch = toupper(ch);
```

And then, because `ch` was just converted to upper-case

```
    if (isupper(ch))      // <-- this is now true
        ch = tolower(ch); // <-- and this is now executed
```

You can solve this with `else`:

```
    if (islower(ch)) {
        ch = toupper(ch);
    } else if (isupper(ch)) {
        ch = tolower(ch);
    }
```

I threw in some braces because I like braces. They help avoid mistakes when you want to add more commands to a branch of the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, when the lowercase letter is converted to uppercase, it will be converted to lowercase, since it is a uppercase letter now. You should do like this:

```
while (cin.get(ch))
{
    if (ch == '@')
        break;
    if (isdigit(ch))
        continue;
    if (islower(ch))
    {
        ch = toupper(ch);
        cout << ch;
        continue;
    }
    if (isupper(ch))
    {
        ch = tolower(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
while (cin.get(ch))
{
    if (ch == '@')
        break;
    else if (isdigit(ch))
        continue;
    else if (islower(ch))
        ch = toupper(ch);
    else if (isupper(ch))
        ch = tolower(ch);

    cout << ch;
}
```